# How to use ansible fail module with block & rescue module

Tags: ansible

Question : When the condition satisfies inside my block, i am failing my play : (- name: Fail my play when condition satisfies : A=NULL), after failure my rescue is not running. All i am trying to achieve here is : Fail the play and set fact and sent notifications

-tasks: 
   - name: Block starts here
   - block:
       - name: step 1
         command: 
       - name: Fail my play when condition satisfies : A=NULL
   - name: Rescue starts here
     rescue:
        - name: set_fact
          set_fact: 
             Result: "{% if ('A=NULL') %}Failure{% endif %}"

```
    - name: Send notification message via Slack
      slack:
       domain: slack.com
       token: value
       username: UserA
       msg: 'Here is my result {{ Result }}'
       validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting in your question appears to be broken, so it is a little unclear what exactly you have tried. Try this:

```
 - block:
     - name: Fail play if A not set
       fail:
         msg: "A is null"
       when: A is null
   rescue:
     - name: Set failure status variable
       set_fact:
         Result: Failure
     - name: Send notification message via Slack
       slack:
         domain: slack.com
         token: value
         username: UserA
         msg: "Here is my result {{ Result }}"
         validate_certs: no
```